# Solr 7 - managed-schema - How to ignore unnamed fields?

Tags: solr

In Solr 6.x I had the following line in the managed-schema to ignore unmapped fields:

```
<dynamicField name="*" type="ignored" multiValued="true" />
```

This line tells Solr 6.x to ignore all unmapped / unnamed fields and worked fine until Solr 7.0.0.

Seems that Solr 7.0.0 does't support `type="ignored"` anymore and gives exception that "ignored" is unknown type.

After some tests, Solr 7 code review, etc, the only solution I have found so far is to have the following line:

```
<dynamicField name="*" type="text_general" multiValued="true" indexed="false" stored="false"/>
```

Seems that it works fine, but what would be the most appropriate / valid solution (configuration) for ignoring unmapped fields (fields that not mapped/named by managed-schema explicitly)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `ignored` field type is just what you've added yourself (and you can add it yourself to the schema if you need it). The old definition was:

```
<fieldType
  name="ignored"
  indexed="false"
  stored="false"
  docValues="false"
  multiValued="true"
  class="solr.StrField" />
```

You probably want to set `docValues` explicitly to false as well now.

Comment: Thank you for clarification! Could you please explain a little bit more on `docValues`? Thanks!

Comment: @Andrew-Gr It's probably better to start with [the ref guide for docvalues](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/docvalues.html) - and ask if anything is unclear :-) In general, docValues is a column oriented storage of field values, so instead of having terms pointing to documents, you have documents pointing to terms. That way you can sum up the terms from the matching documents instead of having to look at all the terms to find matching documents, which is important for Faceting, etc.

Comment: Thank you for pointing to the documentation, definitely will check it as this part somehow passed by without my attention. )

Comment: See also SOLR-217, SOLR-1022.