# Solr Cell turn off metadata extraction

Tags: solr, apache-tika, solr-cell

I am indexing documents with Solr Cell, but I am not interested in metadata at all. Is it possible to turn off metadata extraction by Solr Cell? If yes how can I change request handler settings for this?

Comment: You can use `uprefix=ignored_` to [ignore any unknown fields](https://solr.apache.org/guide/solr/latest/indexing-guide/indexing-with-tika.html#solr-cell-parameters) - i.e. don't define the fields in your schema, and they'll just be silently dropped. This require that you define a dynamic field named `ignored_*` and set it to type "ignored" (which should be a defined field type already, [if not - define it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46509259/solr-7-managed-schema-how-to-ignore-unnamed-fields)).

Comment: Ingoring fields to skip metadata works good, but it feels a bit like a walkaround. Is this the only way to avoid metadata extraction?

Comment: As far as I know, yes. It's also the suggested way in the reference guide.